# adding onclick function to dynamically created html inside $('#data').append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below line of code inside for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
$('#data').append('<div class="time" onclick=showAndroidToast(details[i])></div>);
}
```

showAndroidToast function is getting invoked but It says `i is undefined`

Comment: You're code syntax is wrong. Use `'<div class="time" onclick=showAndroidToast(details[' + i + '])></div>';` instead. - Otherwise you're just printing the letter `i` and passing it to the `showAndroidToast` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate using [`+ operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_())

```js
var details = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Hello'];
for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
  $('#data').append('<div class="time" onclick="showAndroidToast(\'' + details[i] + '\')">Element</div>');
}

function showAndroidToast(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='data'></div>
```

Comment: How to send more than one parameters like showAndroidToast(p1,p2,p3)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. you're inputting i as part of the string, not as the variable.

```
'<div class="time" onclick=showAndroidToast(' + details[i] + ')></div>'
```